# Не удаляется <p> на странице HTML с помощью JS

Tags: javascript, html

```js
const shadowButton = () => {
    const button = document.querySelector('.button');
    const input = document.querySelector('.input');
    button.hidden = true;
    input.addEventListener("input", function () {
        button.hidden = !this.value.length;
    });
};
shadowButton();
const addParagraph = () => {
    const input = document.querySelector('.input');
    const paragraph = document.createElement('p');
    paragraph.innerText = input.value;
    const div = document.querySelector('.divshadow');
    div.append(paragraph);
    if (div.childNodes.length > 7) {
        div.childNodes[2].remove();
    }
};
```

```html
<div class="divshadow">
    <input class="input" type="text">
    <button onclick="addParagraph()" class="button">Click</button>
</div>
```

Не получается удалить p из div, если p становится > 5. Возможно не правильная реализация childNodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const ps = div.querySelectorAll('p');
if (ps.length > 7) {
    ps[2].remove();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`childNodes` включает и текстовые узлы тоже (включая пробелы и переводы строки в разметке, невидимые на странице), не только элементы. Так что условие `if (div.childNodes.length > 7)` выполняется уже тогда, когда вы добавите всего два элемента `p` — потому что с текстовыми узлами элемент `div` уже содержит 5 childNodes в самом начале (два элемента и три текстовых узла). Поэтому же `div.childNodes[2].remove();` удаляет не первый элемент `p`, а всё, что находится после `input`, — сначала текстовый узел между `input` и `button`, потом кнопку.

Comment: Спасибо большое!